# Para atualizar um projeto de Bootstrap v3 para Bootstrap v4 é só alterar os arquivos?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Tenho um projeto que foi feito usando o `Bootstrap v3`, porém eu gostaria de atualiza-lo para a versão 4, para isso, basta trocar os arquivos ou vai ser necessário reescrever novamente?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não, não é só trocar os arquivos, até porque existe uma série de classes novas na versão 4 e outras na versão 3 que foram descontinuadas, além do CSS e o JavaScript que também sofreram alterações...

Os arquivos JavaScript também tem suas diferenças entre as versões 3 e 4 e os componentes de um não funcionam com o Script do outro. O *Combobox* mesmo é um componente que da muito problema quando usado na versão errada.

Outro problema que você pode ter é com os `@medias`, pois os **Grids** são diferentes de uma versão e de outra. Os **Breakings points são diferentes**, logo as colunas não vão ter exatamente a mesma largura entre uma versão e outra.

O próprio **Bootstrap** tem uma *documentação oficial* sobre o **Processo de Migração** de uma versão para a outra

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/